# Publicist badge sometimes not awarded several times over past six months

Tags: support, badges, publicity-badges

I frequently share links to MathSE, Mathoverflow,and MathEdSE on Red it. At first, I received the gold Publicist badge every time the views got to 1000 (for instance, I received a gold badge on MO the day it joined 2.0).

Recently, however, it has been hit or miss. Often, only the bronze badge is awarded. This has occurred on MO and MathEd SE. On the latter site, I have had at least three links viewed 1000 times, and one is close to 10,000 views.

Has there been a change in the way this badge is awarded?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The badge is awarded for *views through your link*, not for the total number of views.

The question may have totalled 1000 views, if only 90 people used your link, you'd still not get a badge for that.

Unless you use an external short-url service like bit.ly to track impressions, you won't know how many times your link was used until you get your badge.

Comment: Yes, I know, but these questions get page views that are thousands of views more than any other questions that week, including hot network questions.

Comment: And how do you know for sure you were the only one sharing a link?

Comment: Because the numbers are so predictable. A post with 4-5 votes on red it will get about 150 extra views total and will set off the announcer badge. Posts with about 20-30 reddit views will get a few hundred views and set off the booster badge. Then posts with 70 or more reddit votes will get over a thousand views and set of the publicist badge. Now one red it post got 161 votes, the question got about 7000 views, and no badge was awarded.

Comment: Except for the bronze. Here's a link:http://www.reddit.com/r/math/comments/22ckbd/more_statistics_mistakes_with_big_effects_i_liked/

Comment: @BrianRushton: There is a possibility that the batch process for handing out the badges is behind. There is also a refererrer guard on  the links (if you come from a Stack Exchange site via the special link, the view doesn't count), and that they tightened this check to *not* count when there is no referrer vs. when there is.

Comment: @BrianRushton Your referral link requires that someone click through to that particular answer, not just the question.

Comment: @jonsca: so? That's still a view for the question too. It's clicking on the link that's enough.

Comment: @MartijnPieters That's my point, there's going to be a lot more views that come in through the question to make up the total view count.

Comment: @jonsca: where on the Reddit page do you see a link to the question? The shared link is of the form `http://sitename/a/<answerid>/<userid>`; you cannot access the question directly from that.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Someone likely posted a link to the question somewhere else, like HN, sorry, I wasn't very clear about that.

Comment: @jonsca: Right, that's what I was already talking about in the comments here; how does the OP know that it was his link that spiked the view count. It then doesn't matter if any other links are for the question or for the answer, anyway.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes, I was never trying to argue with you, I was asking him for clarification as to why he shared the *answer* link in the first place.  I'm still puzzled as to why 161 people voted it up on Reddit and fewer than that might have clicked on it, but it's possible none of them clicked it at all.

Comment: Here is another post of mine on reddit that won the publicist badge in 24 hours with just about 40 votes on reddit: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/117034/the-human-bodys-random-number-generator

Comment: @BrianRushton Like Martijn has pointed out, you really need to bit.ly your links to get an accurate count.  For all you know, 40 guys in a frat house that shares a cable modem could have upvoted your Reddit post.  Not all of those would count as unique views on SE.

Comment: After further testing, it seems the issue is sharing the question vs. sharing the answer. I've got it now. Thanks!